# How to compare if two consecutive fields are same in the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` in which first column is :

```
id = ["6LDFTLL9", "6LDFTLL9", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE","6VPZ4T5P", "EHYXE34N", "EHYXE34N", "TT56GTN2","TT56GTN2" ]
```

I want to check if the consecutive id are same or not. I tried with the following code but it didn't work.

```
i=1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df.id.iloc[i] == df.id.iloc[i + 1]:
     i = i+1
```

Comment: You can get a boolean series by df.id == df.id.shift(). What do you plan to do once you checked if the consecutive ids are same or not?

Comment: if they are same, i wanna do arithmetic operation of two other columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':["6LDFTLL9", "6LDFTLL9", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE","6VPZ4T5P", "EHYXE34N", "EHYXE34N", "TT56GTN2","TT56GTN2" ]})

df['Consec_id'] = df['id'] == df.shift()['id']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          id Consec_id
0   6LDFTLL9     False
1   6LDFTLL9      True
2   7SKDEZWE     False
3   7SKDEZWE      True
4   7SKDEZWE      True
5   7SKDEZWE      True
6   6VPZ4T5P     False
7   EHYXE34N     False
8   EHYXE34N      True
9   TT56GTN2     False
10  TT56GTN2      True
```

Count duplicates:

```
df['Consec_id'].sum()
```

Output

```
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':["6LDFTLL9", "6LDFTLL9", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE","6VPZ4T5P", "EHYXE34N", "EHYXE34N", "TT56GTN2","TT56GTN2" ]})

df[df.id == df.id.shift(1)]
```

will return the ids which are the same as previous ids.

```
    id
1   6LDFTLL9
3   7SKDEZWE
4   7SKDEZWE
5   7SKDEZWE
8   EHYXE34N
10  TT56GTN2
```

If you are looking for identical pairs, more suitable thing to do would be

```
df.loc[(df.id == df.id.shift(1))|(df.id == df.id.shift(-1))]
```

This will provide same ids in the sets of two from where on you can proceed to do further calculations.

```
    id
0   6LDFTLL9
1   6LDFTLL9
2   7SKDEZWE
3   7SKDEZWE
4   7SKDEZWE
5   7SKDEZWE
7   EHYXE34N
8   EHYXE34N
9   TT56GTN2
10  TT56GTN2
```

Note that in this case it only removes the id at index 6 as it doesn't have a matching pair above or below it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By using this data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':["6LDFTLL9", "6LDFTLL9", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE", "7SKDEZWE","6VPZ4T5P", "EHYXE34N", "EHYXE34N", "TT56GTN2","TT56GTN2" ]})
```

Generating a  new column :

```
df['id_2'] = df.id.shift(-1)
df.dropna(inplace= True)
```

now you can compare if two consecutive values are the same by using a simple  filter :

```
df[df['id'] == df[id_2]]
```

and you will get the desired result :

```
        id        id_2
0   6LDFTLL9    6LDFTLL9
2   7SKDEZWE    7SKDEZWE
3   7SKDEZWE    7SKDEZWE
4   7SKDEZWE    7SKDEZWE
7   EHYXE34N    EHYXE34N
9   TT56GTN2    TT56GTN2
```